# How is the language Dart parsed (left to right, received, etc)?

Tags: parsing, dart

I have not been able to find this information in the Documentation for Dart. If someone could provide a code sample that demonstrates this as well that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to give a clear answer to this vague question. But try take a look at the following article and see if that describes what your need: https://mrale.ph/dartvm/

Answer (score 2):

The Dart parser is hand-written to efficiently match the constraints of the, fairly complex, Dart syntax.
The parser is *mainly* recursive, but since the Dart grammar is not purely context-free, it's not just that.

It's impossible to provide a sample that makes any sense. The actual parser code is currently residing in an internal helper package shared by the Dart common front-end and analyzer packages.
The most relevant file would likely be the [parser_impl.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/_fe_analyzer_shared/lib/src/parser/parser_impl.dart) file, but some of the work also happens in the scanner.